# A lower bound on $|S_n - S_{n+1}|$

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading "Durrett: Theory and examples", fourth edition. In page 67, he proves theorem 2.3.7 (an application of Borel Cantelli lemma). During that demonstration, he arrives to a point where:

$X_1,..., X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables, and $S_n$ their sum.

1. $S_n/n$ converges to a finite limit. So $S_n/(n(n+1))$ goes to zero.
2. $|X_n| \geq n$ infinitely often.

So, using that $S_n/n - S_{n+1}/(n+1) = S_n/(n(n+1)) - X_{n+1}/(n+1)$ he states that $|S_n/n - S_{n+1}/(n+1)| > 2/3$ infinitely often. Why does he use two thirds as the lower bound? Since $S_n/(n(n+1))$ goes to zero and $X_{n+1}/(n+1)$ is above 1 infinitely often, I could use $1-\epsilon$ as a lower bound. Am I wrong? Is there any reason to choose $\epsilon = 1/3$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably because $\epsilon = 1/3$ suffices for what followed...... would you prefer he kept writing "for all $\epsilon > 0$" if he didn't need it?

Comment: I get the point, it just seemed to me there might have been a point for that particular election. The proof goes well whatever $\epsilon$ is chosen. There might just no be any reason for the choosing, though :)

Comment: I mean, can't you see if there is a reason? Does he use that $\epsilon$ is specifically $1/3$ anywhere? You have access to the proof.

Comment: I can't tell no reason why using $1/3$, as he only uses the bound to prove that $S_n$ is not a Cauchy series, so it doesn't converge. Any lower bound is useful, as you say it might be just to settle for one.